# Trouble installing JCC (required for pylucene) on mac

Tags: python, macos, pylucene, jcc

I am following closely the [installation guide for pylucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html). I am unable to get past the first step, which requires installing JCC.

To [install JCC the instructions](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/jcc/install.html) briefly note that mac users will need to:

> Edit setup.py and review that values in the INCLUDES, CFLAGS,
>   DEBUG_CFLAGS, LFLAGS and JAVAC are correct for your system. These
>   values are also going to be compiled into JCC's config.py file and are
>   going to be used by JCC when invoking distutils or setuptools to
>   compile extensions it is generating code for.

I am not sure what exactly to edit. I have Java 1.6 installed. When I run the setup.py (without any edits), it gives me the error (which I expect because I haven't edited anything, as instructed):

> > Can't determine where the Java JDK has been installed on this machine. Please set the environment variable JCC_JDK to that location
> >     before running setup.py.

I am a novice coder, so am having trouble finding what I should edit in the setup.py to make this work on a mac? I have tried putting in the file path to java, but this has not helped. Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!